# Working with differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I have various confusions regarding differential forms and operations on forms. I'll illustrate my doubts with a problem from a GR book, but my conceptual problems go a little further. (Sorry if I shouldn't ask different questions all rolled into one; they're just all very related.)

We're given the following Hodge dual of the electromagnetic field tensor: 
$$ \star F = q \sin(\theta) \text{ d}\theta \wedge \text{d} \phi 
$$

**First**

We're asked to find $\text{d}\star F$. Here a few questions pop up from me... What does it mean to find $\text{d}\star F$: To find all of its components? To find a tensorial expression for it? To find an expression in terms of wedge products? I was able to find the non-zero components of $\text{d}\star F$... I don't really know what else to do here.

**Second**

Something strange: Another way I tried was to use:
$$\text{d}(\omega\wedge\eta) = (\text{d}\omega)\wedge \eta +(-1)^q \omega \wedge (\text{d} \eta)  $$
Here, I took $\omega = q\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta $, $\eta=\text{d}\phi$. The second term is zero because $\text{d}^2=0$, while for the first term after calculating component by component, I arrived at $0^*$. What's wrong with doing what I did here?

**Third**

Issues very similar to the first part: we're asked to find $F$ from $\star F$... What does this mean precisely? To find all components of $F$ in this $(\text{d}t,\text{d}\theta,\text{d}\phi,\text{d}r)$ basis? Or to find an expression similar to what we had for $\star F$, using the wedge product? (How could I go from one of these to the other?)

---

*Note: to arrive at this, I did something that I'm not quite sure is correct, so if you could confirm, that'd be great. I used things like $$\text{d}\theta_{\mu}=\text{d}\theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)=\delta_{\theta\mu} \text{ ($1$ for $\mu=\theta$, $0$ otherwise)}$$
Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First

Express $\mathrm d \star F$ on an explicit form similar to the one in the right hand side of the formula for $\star F$.

#### Second

Why do you think that the result $0$ is wrong? I think that it's correct:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm d \star F
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(q \sin(\theta)\right) 
\underbrace{\mathrm d\theta \wedge \mathrm d\theta \wedge \text{d} \phi}_{= 0} \\
& + \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\left(q \sin(\theta)\right) 
\underbrace{\mathrm d\phi \wedge \mathrm d\theta \wedge \text{d} \phi}_{= 0} \\
& + \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(q \sin(\theta)\right)}_{= 0} 
\mathrm dr \wedge \mathrm d\theta \wedge \text{d} \phi \\
& + \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(q \sin(\theta)\right)}_{= 0}
\mathrm dt \wedge \mathrm d\theta \wedge \text{d} \phi \\
& = 0
\end{align}$$

#### Third

Find an expression similar to the right hand side of the formula for $\star F$.

Comment: For the second part: I'm sorry, I don't understand - how did you calculate that? I'm not sure how you go from the left hand side to the right hand side.

For the first and third parts: I should've been clearer, part of my question is also how exactly to find a similar sort of expression (sort of what you did in the second part, but I'm not familiar with the "rule" you used to calculate that). 

Ps. I assumed it wouldn't be 0 because later in the question I am asked to integrate it.

Comment: By definition, if $\omega = f \, \mathrm dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm dx_{i_m}$ then $\mathrm df = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} \mathrm dx_k \wedge \mathrm dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm dx_{i_m}$. I have just applied this to $\omega = \star F = q \sin(\theta) \, \mathrm d\theta \wedge \mathrm d\phi$.

Comment: If you haven't seen that definition for the exterior derivative, what definition do you use? Perhaps in terms of axioms, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_axioms ?

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'd seen the definition in terms of components (and the axioms one), and hadn't quite connected it to what you applied.